# How to create a controller in a sub-directory in codeigniter v4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

In codeigniter v3 sub-directory in a controller is working fine. But in codeigniter v4 this is not working.

**Folder structure:**
`Controllers/[sub-directory name]/Controller_name.php`

**Need this Url:**
`htp://domain.com/[sub-directory name]/controller_name/`

How can I solve this in Codeigniter v4?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the BaseController you have to specify "which one", using USE or you can explicitly specify it each time you use an object.

So you could have (**as deste had answered**) but using BaseController

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Ajax;

    class Test extends \App\Controller\BaseController // Which BaseController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return 'controller works!';
        }
    }
```

OR the nicer way using "use" is to specify exactly which BaseController you want to use once.

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Ajax;

use App\Controllers\BaseController; // Which BaseController are you referring to.

class Test extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'controller works!';
    }
}
```

It's a matter of telling PHP Where your files are.

Not the clearest of explanations but think of it as you have to say "where something is".

I strongly recommend reading over the [Codeigniter User Guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) a few more times and messing around with it more to get the hang of how it all works.
You might also like to read **[Primer: Namespaces & CodeIgniter 4](https://www.patreon.com/posts/primer-4-19847047)** by [Lonnie Ezell](https://github.com/lonnieezell) (one of CodeIgniter's developers).

Using "Namespaces" and "use" you can create HMVC structures or anything you like. They are powerful and once you get the basics, very simple.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar yet with CodeIgniter 4 and namespaces... But I suppose that it's a namespace issue.

I have tried to replicate your case. I created a directory ./App/Controllers/ajax and inside this a Test.php file:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Ajax;

class Test extends \CodeIgniter\Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'controller works!';
    }
}
```

`https://myserver/ajax/test` page work fine.
I hope this can help you in some way.

Comment: Working fine. But **BaseController** is not found here. I want to extend previous folders **BaseController** here. I mean common **BaseController** for all controller. Is this possible?

Comment: @ParagDhali If you have just changed controller to BaseController, yes it won't be found as you have not specidifed where it is. The CI Documentation should have given you a clue but I have answered it above.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I just create a new **BaseController** in **sub-directory**. And it's works fine. But I want to extend the existing **BaseController** (default) from other controller  which is exists in **sub-directry**. I mean, I don't want to use **multiple BaseController(s)**. If any example you have, please share. Thank you!

Comment: You have the tools at your disposal, so experiment.